# How to test play sound in php

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

need your help to understand how to test playing audio. maybe somebody had an experience with it.

so. we store audio files like blob in the database. (know its not a good variant)

**questions1:** how to seed the database with fake data?
I create a tmp folder with test file test.mp3 and do *file_get_contents('/tmp/test.mp3', false)*

**question2:** how to test the endpoint for playing audio?
in my unit test

- I seed the DB with this test file
- then make a GET request to the endpoint
- and then compare the body from the response and my tmp file

Im not sure that this is the correct variant

Comment: You can play that sound with javascript, after fetch the mp3 file

Comment: we have api. And I have to test it on the PHP  side

Comment: You can't really test that the audio plays. You may be able to verify that the file you are sending to the front end is set and is of the expected type.

Comment: how can I get the type of my blob?

        $finfo    = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $mimeType = $finfo->buffer($file);